# Unable to get JSON values separately in Android

Tags: android, json

I have a trouble finding a way how to parse JSONArray

This is my JSON:

```
{
   "result": [
 [
         "id",
         "name",
         "origin",
         "destination"
      ],
      [
         1,
         "A S Peta",
         0,
         0
      ],
      [
         2,
         "Aachara",
         0,
         0
      ],
.
.
.
[
         2238,
         "sydney",
         0,
         0
      ]
]
}
```

I need to access it in Android app. I have tried and I am able to receive values, but they are displaying in a single row, and I am unable to split the fields.

```
if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("result");
                for (int i = 1; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
              String name = contacts.getString(i).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "");
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();
                    contact.put("name", name);
                  contactList.add(contact);
                }

            }
```

This is my output, I need to get the values separately like:

```
1  
A S Peta  
0  
0
```

But not in single row:

[image]

Comment: you have two JSONArray in your JSON  "result": [
 [ Please change that or use two JSONArray in your code in android

Comment: The problem is your `...replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "")`, which will just get `the ith string`.(P.S. your json format is messy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your code with this

```
if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

            // Getting JSON Array node
            JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("result");
            for (int i = 1; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
         JSONArray contactArray = contacts.getJSONArray(i);
         int id = contactArray.getInt(0);
         String name = contactArray.getString(1);
         String origin= contactArray.getString(2);
         String destination= contactArray.getString(3);
                HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();
                contact.put("id", id);
                contact.put("name", name);
                contact.put("origin", origin);
                contact.put("destination", destination);
              contactList.add(contact);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank You so So So much You have made My Day Thank You Once again

Answer (score 4):

Json String ca be parsed in JSONObject like:

```
try {
        List<HashMap<String,String>> cityDetails= new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("your json string");
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
        JSONArray cityKeyArray =jsonArray.getJSONArray(0);

        for(int index=1; index<jsonArray.length();index++){
            HashMap<String, String> cityData = new HashMap<String, String>();
            for(int dataIndex=0; dataIndex<cityKeyArray.length();dataIndex++) {
               cityData.put(cityKeyArray.getString(dataIndex), jsonArray.getJSONArray(index).getString(dataIndex));
            }
            cityDetails.add(cityData);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**cityDetails** can be used in the adapter to show value according to the keys which are in the first array of the JSON String i.e. **cityKeyArray**. 
So, the collections will show the data as user requirements.

Hope this will help to solve your query. 
Thanks and Happy coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
String name = contacts.getString(i).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "");
```

Do not do this; it seems you do not have strings for your arrays.

You have nested lists, it seems, so you can access those  JSON arrays via another `getJSONArray(index)` method

Or you could fix the source of the JSON (your server?) to return better parsable JSON

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

            // Getting JSON Array node
            JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("result");

            for (int i = 1; i < contacts.length(); i++) {

                HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();
                contact.put("name", contacts.getString("name"));
              contactList.add(contact);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
 if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

            // Getting JSON Array node
            JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("result");
            for (int i = 1; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                JsonArray array=contacts.get(i);
          String name = array.getString("name");
                HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();
                contact.put("name", name);
              contactList.add(contact);
            }

        }
```